# Environment Variables in JAVA (tomcat)

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, tomcat8, environment

I have my `/etc/environment` as follows

`APP="/opt/apps/"
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"`

I have sourced `source /etc/environment` on my machine. I am able to get the output when I type `echo $APP` on terminal

But When I call it from inside a java file

`LOGGER.error("APP: " + System.getenv("APP"));
LOGGER.error("PATH: " + System.getenv("PATH"));
LOGGER.error("JAVA_HOME: " + System.getenv("JAVA_HOME"));`

I get only the output of PATH but not the other 2 env variables.

**OUTPUT**

`2017-12-18 07:22:10 ERROR JRWebService:127 - APP: null
2017-12-18 07:22:10 ERROR JRWebService:128 - PATH:/ usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
2017-12-18 07:22:10 ERROR JRWebService:129 - JAVA_HOME: null`

Please correct me what am I doing wrong

Comment: check this System.getProperty("JAVA_HOME");

Comment: what do you get when you try the `EnvMap` example from [the tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html)?

Comment: Even PATH variable values are mismatching.

Comment: I think you should reboot your system if no reboot is done before

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like APP and JAVA_HOME are not exported. With unix shells, there is a difference between set (variable is visible in your current shell) and export (variable is visible to all sub-processes). If you just type "X=Y", X it is set, but not exported. PATH is mostly exported somewhere already.

You can test this by running "`export | grep APP`" in your console. If APP doesn't show up, the variable will not be visible to java, or any other program you run, even though `echo $APP` works just fine.

If this is the case, simply add "export APP" to your .profile, or the script with which you are starting your java application (or to test, simply type that on the console before you start java).

Comment: Running `export | grep APP` gives the following result `declare -x APP="/opt/apps/"` But still I am unable to access it inside JAVA

Comment: @Jay How and from where are you starting java? I mean:
- Are you starting it from the console as java YourClassName
- are you running it using a script
- or are we talking about a web app that runs as a service?

Comment: I am deploying a war file on tomcat server. My tomcat is located at /opt/tomcat. Version 8.*

Comment: Then you will need to source or set the /etc/environment variables that you need _inside the tomcat / catalina start scripts_, since tomcat is not run with your shell's environment. If you need further help on this I would recommend to add #tomcat to your question and change the phrasing of the question accordingly, so that people who know more about Tomcat can help you.

Comment: Added tomcat. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't source your /etc/environment. That is not the way to get variables into your process. The /etc/environment file is not a script, so it makes no sense to source it. It is just a list of settings, a bit like a properties file.

See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/339617/how-to-reload-etc-environment-without-rebooting) for more details.

It is read when you login. Therefore, to make the variables visible, you should logout and back in.

Comment: I have already rebooted the system but it has no effect. I am getting output when I issue echo $APP but the same variable is not accessible in the java file